# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 10"

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, ide

I am trying to make a application which would generate numbers b/w two inputted numbers but getting this error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 10"

```js
int start, end;
start = Integer.parseInt(TF1.getText());
end = Integer.parseInt(TF2.getText());


while (start <= end);

{

  TA1.setText(" " + start);
  start++;

}
```

Comment: the space before ten is what is throwing the error

Comment: `start  = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText().trim());`